# MySQL weird float and decimal behaviour

Tags: mysql, floating-point, decimal

I have a table contain column `float(10,5)` and `decimal(10,5)`

I update the table to be:

```
update table1
set decimaltesting = 12311123123123123.456789,
floattesting = 12311123123123123.456789;
```

The result become:

```
decimal = 99999.99999
float = 100000.00000
```

but if I change column to `float(6,3)` and `decimal(6,3)` and update it with the same value as above

The result become:

```
float = 999.999
decimal = 999.999
```

Why for the first scenario, float value will be `100000.00000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Garbage in - garbage out**

Remember this simple rule. Your statement will not be correct in common case - since, for example, with strict sql mode it will fail with error. But since you're getting results as you've described, I assume you have allowed such behavior. The correct point is - that your application *is aware* about it's models data types - and so such things are under control - and you're not passing garbage to your DBMS, resulting with garbage as well.

**Always about precision**

Your sample is a good demonstration about - what's the difference between fixed-point and floating-point data types. First thing - according to [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> When a floating-point or fixed-point column is assigned a value that
>   exceeds the range implied by the specified (or default) precision and
>   scale,  MySQL stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint
>   of that range.

-that is why you're seeing that `999.999` and so on. But - what about strange `100000.00000`? The hint is - that you can see this only with floating point field. Why? Because MySQL will convert your out-of-range value to maximum allowed by your field, but, since floating point values are stored approximately, there's [*no guarantee*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html) that final value will hold precision - and, therefore, it may result in your `100000.00000` value. Note, that such thing will never happen with fixed-point data type.